# What are banes in Lightbringer series and how do they create gods?

Tags: lightbringer

Banes are not clear to me even though I checked [Wikia page](https://lightbringer-series.fandom.com/wiki/Bane) for Lightbringer.

AFAIK;

- Banes are used to create gods
- They deteriorate everything around them but mostly own color users

So here are my questions:

- What is a bane and how do they come to life?
- When slain, do they reoccur or that color's bane never exists anymore?
- How do they lead to gods?
- Do they have consciousness?

No spoiler please, I'm currently halfway through 3rd book, *The Broken Eye*.

Comment: The bane will get constant discussion throughout The Broken Eye (pay attention to Liv) and The Blood Mirror (book 4). But most of the mechanics of the situation are at the end of The Blinding Knife (book 2).

Comment: I won't vote to close as I'm not familiar with Lightbringer to make an educated guess on how related these questions are but it seems like this could be too broad.

Comment: @Jontia So, it's RAFO? I thought I might have missed (I'm not fluent in English and there is no translation of this book into my mother tongue). Thanks :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think it is not broad as much as you think. Banes are important but minor in the series and not knowing the answers is not vital either. I was just curious because I could not find anything anywhere.

Comment: I don't think it's too broad. The biggest problem with this as a question is the "no spoiler please". Because the answer is in the next half of the book. Well not really an answer, but more details with more to come.

Comment: @Jontia I'm always OK with "RAFO" answer and always fear that I missed something. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it violates Future Works policy, albeit works that have now been published by invoking a "no-spoilers" position. Answers are nearly always spoilers.